# synonyms offline Dictionary for a search application

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, wordnet, synonym

i'm trying to build a smart search engine application that gets synonyms of the words in the Question and Query my database with each of the generated synonyms

the problem is that i'm searching for a way to get all synonyms of the words in the Question using a dictionary or something. that could in the end offers 
1- direct synonyms  like :  file > movie  , football > soccer 
2- could offer a matchstring like  : population size >  number of citizens (optional ) 
3- something that is fast and reliable . prefered to be hosted offline not an API for a service

i explored :

- [WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/) but the problem is that it takes a lot of time due to that it's used online
- [Watson synonyms](http://watson.kmi.open.ac.uk/API/explain-syn.html)  not very efficient , and it takes a lot of , (api to an online service )

i wonder if there are some other efficient alternatives

Answer (score 2):

You could use [WordNet offline](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/download).

Comment: What should I download to make it work offline? I've downloaded WordNet 3.1 DATABASE FILES ONLY but don't know what to do with them. Thanks EDIT: I want to work with those synonyms in Python.