# WordNet in offline mode - Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, offline, wordnet

I'm creating a program which needs to find synonyms of a given word. I tried Nltk module - `Nltk.corpus.wordnet` but this is too slow. It's because this is an online version. So I tried to find a way to use it offline - download it's data.

I've tried  this [Link to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684877/synonyms-offline-dictionary-for-a-search-application) way, downloaded `WordNet-2.1.exe` from [this link](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/#win), but it installs only this program: `Remove Duplicate Lines & Words In Multiple Text Files Software`.

So I tried to download `WordNet 3.1 DATABASE FILES ONLY` on that page, but it contains some files which didn't help me (maybe I don't know how).

Can somebody give me an advice how to make WordNet offline works (the only lib I need is synonyms)? 
It is possible to make it to work as a Python module or some csv file?

Comment: Corpuses that aren't for public use (except with certain tools) can be obfuscated. Is the corpus available for public use? Also, I'm not sure what "unknown files" means.

Comment: @keyser I don't know how to use them. I've edited the question. It should be for public use, as far as I know I can use it, but I have to use a citation. I want to use it in my bachelor thesis.

Comment: I would pickle the wordnet as a dictionary to speed things up, or use an api like BigHugeLabs to get and store synonyms in a pickled dict.

Answer (score 0):

Look at chapter: [for-application-developer](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/frequently-asked-questions/for-application-developer/)
You can find there what is the format of offline files and C API documentation link:
[API](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wnintro.3WN.html)`

Comment: both links are broken